# How does (kg/m^3) * (m/s^2) * (m) come out to be units of N/m^2?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, unit-conversion

To me it seems to come out to be kg/(m*s^2). Is this somehow equivalent to N/m^2?

Comment: Use the fact that N = kg m/s^2 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition

1 N = 1 kg m/s^2

To remember this, remember F = ma. The left hand side has units of force. The right hand side is kg * (m/s^2).

dividing both sides by m^2, we get

1 N/m^2 = 1 kg / (m s^2)